# Having trouble using jQuery to set meta tag values

Tags: jquery, meta-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use javascript to change the meta-tags of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568760/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-to-change-the-meta-tags-of-the-page)

I'm trying to set meta tags using jQuery (please don't reply that this doesn't make sense since search engines blah-blah-blah... I am loading invoking 3rd party Javascript functions that examine these vales, such as Tweetmeme and Facebook).

If I use:

```
 $('meta[name=some-name]').attr('content', 'some value');
```

it does work to set the value of an existing meta tag, but does not create a meta tag if such a named one does not exist.

If you have insight or experience with this, please reply...

Comment: What jQuery code are you using to create the tag?

Answer (score 12):

You can do this, not the cleanest, but what you're trying to do is pretty odd so there's not a great way to handle it:

```
var mt = $('meta[name=some-name]');
mt = mt.length ? mt : $('<meta name="some-name" />').appendTo('head');
mt.attr('content', 'some value');
```

The conditional expression in there checks `.length`, which is 0 or `false` if not found, if that's the case we create the element and append it to the head, whether it was added or originally found, `mt` is set to the `<meta>` with that name now, and you can set the attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the code Nick. What I'm doing may seem strange, but its a 100% client-side app and so as the user does things, the value of the Meta tags need to change to reflect the present state.

Comment: hi, shouldn't it be: mt.attr('some-name', 'some value');

Comment: @Andresch - nope, we're setting the `content="some value"` attribute of the `<meta>` tag, it's a specific attribute of that element...you can read more about it here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4.2

Answer (score 6):

Leveraging Nick's code, I made a function to do the meta tag setting, creating if necessary. Should this be of use to anyone...

```
    function setOrCreateMetaTag(metaName, name, value) {
        var t = 'meta['+metaName+'='+name+']';
        var mt = $(t);
        if (mt.length === 0) {
            t = '<meta '+metaName+'="'+name+'" />';
            mt = $(t).appendTo('head');
        }
        mt.attr('content', value);
    }
```

The metaName most often might be assumed to be "name" but I am also having to set "property" as well, so made the function handle a meta meta-name.

Comment: can I suggest changing the function to return `mt`? You might want to perform other actions on it too.

Comment: Ah, chaining, of course. Thanks for the reminding me of the pattern!

Answer (score 6):

I was just experimenting with this a bit on iOS. It turned out that it was possible to dynamically set a meta tag to prevent zooming on iOS like so:

```
$('<meta>', {
 name: 'viewport',
 content: 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1'
}).appendTo('head');
```

Removing it however, didn't re-enable zooming:

```
$('meta[name=viewport]').remove();
```

But overwriting the meta tag:

```
$('meta[name=viewport]').attr(
 'content',
 'width=980, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=1.6'
);
```

with its default values did.

Comment: I believe that the first line of the last code block should be:
  /*  $('meta[name=viewport]').attr(  */  
I added a '.