# Trying to set MetaTag dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meta-tags

i'm trying to dynamically set a metatag to the head of my document. This is a mobile device specific metatag that I need to add through code. I found this solution here:

[Having trouble using jQuery to set meta tag values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831529/having-trouble-using-jquery-to-set-meta-tag-values)

but it doesnt seem to work, what am I doing wrong?

```
function setOrCreateMetaTag(metaName, name, value) {
    var t = 'meta['+metaName+'='+name+']';
    var mt = $(t);
    if (mt.length === 0) {
        t = '<meta '+metaName+'="'+name+'" />';
        mt = $(t).appendTo('head');
    }
    mt.attr('content', value);
}

setOrCreateMetaTag(name, viewport, 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0');
```

Comment: Do you have to set this in Javascript? What about doing it server-side?

Comment: also, I know this is a minor thing, but couldn't (mt.length===0) just be (!mt.length) ?

Comment: yeah, I need to do this in Javascript. It relies on an action in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things. First make sure you are including jQuery, since the $() is a jQuery method. This means including something like:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The second, I don't think you really meant to pass variables name and viewport. Rather, you should pass the strings like:

```
setOrCreateMetaTag('name', 'viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you would need quotes around name and viewport, unless these are variables set somewhere else:

```
setOrCreateMetaTag('name', 'viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0');
```

Comment: .. but isn't that the same as the previous persons answer though?