# Weirdness on Android 2.1 browser: Twitter user page doesn't load

Tags: android, browser, twitter, webkit

The URL which points to the user "coopthink" which works in most browsers, including Chrome and Safari on iOS is:

http://www.twitter.com/coopthink

However, if I try this on Android (I'm writing an app, but this even occurs directly in the browser), it redirects to:

https://mobile.twitter.com/#!/coopthink

and then says "Sorry, that page doesn't exist". Any idea what is wrong and what would be the correct URL?

**EDIT**: This seems to work on Android 2.2 and higher; only 2.1 (and possibly lower) show this problem.

Comment: nope worked for me both in browser and android

Comment: Hmm, I just tried on a 2.3 emulator and it worked for me too. My phone is 2.1 as was the emulator -- need to investigate more ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on a 2.2 and 2.1 emulator. I was getting some strange behavior previously with Android 2.2 and meta-tags on an emulator. See my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604886/android-not-respecting-metatag-removal). It seems to be a bug with hashes and lower versions of the emulator code. I haven't tested it though on an actual device of the same generation.