# Modify prototype of a metatag object

Tags: javascript, dom, metatag

I'm dynamically generating metatags. I'm able to append the properties of the object that are part of the metatag prototype by default. `name`, `content` and `ID`. But when I try to append something different to the object, say `foo` it doesn't append.

How do I add my own property so I can add to it in the same way I'm adding the `name` `id` and `content` in the example.

```
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];        
var metaNode = document.createElement('meta');
metaNode.name = "name"; //appends
metaNode.id = "id"; //appends
metaNode.content = "content"; //appends
metaNode.foo = "bar"; //doesn't append
headID.appendChild(metaNode);
```

result: `<meta id="id" name="name" content="content">`

**want:** `<meta id="id" name="name" content="content" foo="bar">`

Comment: are you using a library?

Comment: What is the point of generating meta tags this way?  Very few, if any, robots or crawlers are going to run your javascript and thus they won't see your generated meta tags.  They will only see meta tags that are in the actual source of your page.

Comment: sissonb I'm using jQuery in other places. jfriend00 Thanks, I'll have to see and test.

Comment: also metatags aren't only for robots/web crawlers, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604886/android-not-respecting-metatag-removal but in this case I'm using it for a crawler, so I'll have to see if it works. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

metaNode.setAttribute('foo', 'bar');

Answer (score 1):

A more standards compliant way of doing this would be to prefix it with `data-`:

```
metaNode.setAttribute("data-foo", "bar");
```

Though, the result would be:

```
<meta id="id" name="name" data-foo="bar" />
```

Comment: setAttribute has been around since ie5. Do you mean HTML way? Or prefixing with data- is the HTML5 way?

Comment: @sissonb You're right, and as such I reworded it a bit. Originally, I was talking about prefixing with `data-`.

Comment: @sissonb - setAttribute was introduced in the [W3C DOM Core level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html) in 1998, [IE 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_5) was released in 1999, so  I think it's better to say "setAttribute has been around for a very long time". It's also fair to say that was buggy in IE for the whole time, at least until IE 9.

Comment: @RobG I agree, it would be much better to use a library so you don't run into IE issues. I've only run into rendering issues with setAttribue in IE, and the meta tag isn't rendered so there shouldn't be an issue in this case.

Comment: I don't use setAttribute at all (at least extremely rarely), I only deal with standard DOM properties because they are reliable and consistent cross browsers and it's a lot faster to access a property directly than call a function to access the same thing (e.g. why do `element.getAttribute('id')` when `element.id` is faster, less to type and easier to read). For anything else I use a javascript object, which is also fast, reliable and independent of DOM objects and their (possibly conflictingly named) attributes and properties.

Comment: in this case metaNode.foo = "bar"; didn't set the attribute, but metaNode.setAttribute('foo', 'bar'); did. I usually avoid writing code at this level and just use a library.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a property to a DOM object, some browsers will also add an attribute with the same name regardless of what it is (e.g. IE) others will only add the attribute if the name is the same as a standard attribute (e.g. Firefox).

If you really want to deal with non-standard attributes, use get/setAttribute, but it is a bit buggy in IE so only use it for non-standard attributes, use properties for everything else. And if you are adding non-standard properties, it is best to store them in a javascript object rather than modifying DOM objects (mostly because you might be stomping on standard DOM properties or those added by other code).

Also, DOM objects are host objects so might not like you adding non-standard properties (again, there's no spec that says they have to let you).

Lastly, there is no reason to believe that there is a meta element constructor, that it has a prototype or that instances of meta elements inherit from that prototype. Some browsers implement javascript-like prototype inheritance for DOM objects, others don't. There is nothing that says DOM objects **must** use prototype inheritance (and some don't).