# Effect of adding a Robots-Meta-Tag in an Ajax application

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, meta-tags, robots.txt

There are plenty of questions and answers about how to add a `<meta>` tag to the DOM using Javascript. I'm interested only in the effectiveness of this strategy in relation to the `<meta name="robots" content="noindex"/>` tag.

- Will the crawler respect this meta-tag on a page, if that tag is created late? Does it matter *how* late?
- What are the best practices for an AJAX application where some pages are indexable, others not? The HTML is loaded only once, the DOM modified based on the application state / current page. I have read through Google's [documentation on the robots meta tag](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag) and their [deprecation of the AJAX crawling scheme](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) but could not find any information.
- Is there maybe a way to "test" what the googlebot would think about a particular URL?

PS: I don't think this is a duplicate of [Ajax Loaded meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120686/ajax-loaded-meta-tags), since that post is now five years old and the answer has been deprecated.