# Meta tag refresh in minutes

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<meta name="redirection" http-equiv="refresh" 
      content="2;url=http://www.google.com">
```

It redirects to google.com after 2 seconds. Instead of 2 seconds to make the redirection after 2 minutes just need to change `content="120"`.

Problem:
The numerical value is configure in Database in minutes (30 minutes),in seconds its `(30*60=1800)`. How to do this calculation and set dynamically the meta tag's  content to `1800`.

I tried using jquery

```
var value = "1800;http://wwww.google.com";  
$('meta[name="redirection"]').attr("content", value);
```

its not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568760/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-to-change-the-meta-tags-of-the-page

Comment: You can create the tag dynamically at the server side

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question because either it should be done server side (in which case this question doesn't provide any of the necessary detail), or it should be done with JavaScript (in which case RC's link has the answer).

Comment: plz let me know , how to do this on server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create a meta tag client side, e.g. like this:

```
var foo = document.createElement('meta'), refreshtime = 1800;
foo.setAttribute('http-equiv','refresh');
foo.setAttribute('content',refreshTime+';url=http://www.google.com');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(foo);
```

Or using jquery:

```
$('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="'+refreshtime+
     ';url=http://www.google.com"/>')
 .appendTo($('head'));​
```

Comment: nice approach , it does create meta tag inside head , but redirection doesn't happen .. any idea

Comment: If you're loading a page in an Iframe, it may be restricted by security constraints. See http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/LXzVU/ for a working example

Comment: `appendTo($('head';))` contains a `;`. Furthermore the path to jquery (`src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js`) is not a full path.

Comment: Additionally you should use a *full url* for redirecting: `url=http://yahoo.com`

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>    
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
var refreshTime= 2*2;
    var foo = document.write('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="'+refreshTime+';url=http://www.google.com">');
</script>

</head>

<body>

Meta tag testing

</body>

</html>
```

Just found that , it can be also done using document.write