# Will Search Engines grab javascript generated keyword and description meta tags?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, seo, meta-tags

I have a website that loads its template via ajax.
The `description` and `keywords` meta tags are present on this `template.html` file and not on the current `index.html` page being loaded. After the template is loaded it will embed the meta tags from the template into `index.html` file.

Will Google or any other search engine be able to read this page's `description` and `keywords` meta tags which were dynamically inserted?

I'm asking this because I've heard that many search engines don't support javascript, although, when getting a preview screenshot from the website search result on google it displays the page containing the whole layout (after the insertion of `template.html`) so this made me a but curious.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pretty sure this has been asked here before

Comment: SEO questions are not actually programming-related. This belongs in http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I believe I saw few question related to changing meta tags dynamically here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568760/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-to-change-the-meta-tags-of-the-page but unfortunately I couldn't find any related on how search engines will interpret this. sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding HTML to the DOM with JavaScript [has been shown](http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/can-google-really-access-content-in-javascript-really) to work with Google's crawl. So the real question is if using this method still works for meta tag markup. You'll need to run your own test, as no one else seems to have run a case study on this before.

Comment: thanks Zachary it turns out that Google doesn't read dynamically inserted meta keyword and description tags, once I've set up directly on the page took few days and google adjusted its results. so the answer in this case was really No.

Comment: Can you post the code so we can see how you did it? Also did you make sure that the last cache date of that page is after the change?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is NO! Most search engines dont crawl over links or words dynamically added by javascript!

Comment: That's not true. Google supports most simple methods of adding HTML to the DOM. http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/can-google-really-access-content-in-javascript-really