# Full Ajax library auto update meta tag

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using Full Ajax library in my site, but i found a problem.
The script automatically update 
but I also want to update meta tag.

please tell me how to update meta tag, please update the fullAjax library so that it will automatically update tag = author, description and keyword.

I have uploaded the FullAjax to JsFiddle [JSfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/raryan/HJpxK/)

Comment: Why do you need to update meta? From my perspective it doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568760/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-to-change-the-meta-tags-of-the-page