# Why is my dynamic changing of my meta description tag not changing it?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web, meta-tags

Inspired by Stephen Ostermiller's answer to my question here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53306/is-the-programmatic-addition-of-keywords-and-descriptions-worthwhile/53307?noredirect=1#comment53439_53307, I found here: [Is it possible to use javascript to change the meta-tags of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568760/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-to-change-the-meta-tags-of-the-page) this snippet of code:

```
$('meta[name=description]').remove();
$('head').append('<meta name="description" content="Find and optionally acquire all current and past Hugo award winning books">');
```

Unfortunately, on adding this code to the appropriate place (where the Hugo awards are loaded into the page), when I run the new version of the site and choose "View Page Source", I still see the same old description:

```
<meta name="description" content="Find and optionally acquire all current and past book, movie, and music award winners, such as Pulitzers for books, Oscars/Academy Awards for movies, and Grammies for music, as well as many other awards" />
```

(and it is not at the end of all the meta tags, as I would expect it to be if my code worked).

What am I doing wrong or missing here?

Comment: view source gets the original source of the file, not the changes made by javascript etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the description it'd be more straight forward to do this

```
$('meta[name="description"]').attr('content','new content');
```

I hope that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Metatag is used by the Google crawler and Google crawler does not support javascript
so, you can not set metatags using javascript

Comment: wrong! google started pulling up the right values for meta descriptions with quite some accuracy when it comes to dynamic meta tag updation on ajax content.