# Updating IE10 pinned site's back/forward buttons' color without refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-10, pinned-site

Currently, my page contains the following meta tags in the `<head>`:

```
<meta name="application-name" content="MLP Now" />
<meta name="msapplication-starturl" content="./" />
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#C693FB"/>
<meta name="msapplication-tooltip" content="MLP Now" />
```

This works just fine, and the browser happily updates the button color to match the set value. But here's the catch, this only happens when the page is reloaded.

I don't want to force my users to reload just to see their button color being changed, so I was curious if there's a way to do this without reloading the page.

I tried changing the value of the meta tag with JavaScript, but it doesn't work, as you might expect.

```
var newcolor = "#123456";
$('meta[name="msapplication-navbutton-color"]').attr('content',newcolor);
```

**Edit:** To clarify, the meta tag *does* get updated, only the buttons don't change color in IE.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568760/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-to-change-the-meta-tags-of-the-page

Comment: Do you got javascript running on this page ?

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle or add this code to your question. Thanks.

Comment: @OlivierH Well, I could link all 13 of my seperate JS files, but I feel they are irrelevant.

Comment: Is this only custom js or do you use some librairies/frameworks ? Which ones ?

Comment: You can try to use the .html() property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try to remove and add meta tag
- Try to repaint all page. Add html element repaint css styles via `display: inline-block`
- Very bad way but ... try `document.documentElement.innerHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML`

I hope it will help you.

**New**

I read [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg491732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#runtime) and it was helpful. `msapplication-navbutton-color` is a runtime parameter, it means styles apply only once, when page start loading...So you can't to change color. After page load changing runtime styles(domNode.runtimeStyle) and metadata like `msapplication-navbutton-color` do not trigger repaint behavior.

Comment: Adding/removing meta tag failed. I could already tell repainting the page wouldn't do anything, so the last two aren't good either.