# Changing Viewport in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I want to render an Ember application in browser with as much native feel as possible. One of things I want to do is disable zooming and side to side movement which just serves as a distraction. As I understand it the way to achieve this goal is to set:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

and it appears that even if I set this property in my `application.hbs` template I get a default setting of:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I'd like to change this, ideally having it be dynamic (as there are a few pages where zooming would be appropriate), but if static is the only option I just need to override the default.

Comment: Are you using the cli?

Comment: Yes I am using the CLI

Comment: Find the index.html file and modify it there, application template and all other templates are rendered in the body.

Comment: Ok. Guess that means it'll need to be a static setting?

Comment: yup, unless you feel like [modifying it via javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2568760/1401094) depending on the route you're on.