# Populate meta content attribute with Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

My variable is defined as fallows:

```
$("figure.entry-featured-media-boxed").each(function () {
        var a_href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');

    });
```

And i want to populate the content from the meta with name : fbimg

```
<meta property="og:image" name="fbimg" content="" />
```

Can this be done ?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Do you want to add multiple `meta` tags to the DOM (as in one for each link in the matched set of elements)?

Comment: no i just want to add the content that a_href contains ionto the content of the meta tag

Comment: I asked because you are looping through what appears to be a set of elements. If you know you are only going to retrieve one element, you should skip the `each` loop and just reference the link's href directly.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$('meta[name=fbimg]').attr('content', a_href);
```

but in an each this would be pointless, since you will overwrite the value every time you're looping through the each...

Might be interesting for you to also check: [Is it possible to use javascript to change the meta-tags of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568760/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-to-change-the-meta-tags-of-the-page)