# Meta Tags not showing up

Tags: javascript, meteor, telescope

The meta tags are not showing up in View Page Source in my meteor app. But when i view in Inspect Element its showing.

`<meta name="fragment" content="!">
<title>Loading...</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <link id="rss-link" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="New Posts" href="/feed.xml"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicon.png">`

The above code snippet is from the  view page source.

Comment: Maybe meteor is creating meta tags dynamically in javascript.-

Comment: @VickyGonsalves   Won't that affect my SEO? I am using embedly and View Source to see what gets pulled from my site and I see it shows as 'Loading...' in both cases for the title even  though I have the title specified explicitly in the header and even as a meta tag in header.  What could be causing this issue?

Comment: I dont think it can be an issue if crawler fetches the meta tags.

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4251913/1548301