# How to implement FB meta tags for a specific item within a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a music player, and each track have a share button. The following is my method for sharing:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A//www.website.com/#music-player-track1">Share on Facebook</a>
```

So I want to give this share button specific image, and description. As far as I know the Facebook meta tags must be located in the header of the page. So how can I have various meta tags for each track that I am sharing?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of tracks in a view model / data object of sorts, I would suggest iterating over them, generating meta tags, and inserting them into your header.  Your meta data does not have to be in line with your share button (as you alluded to in your question).

If you have multiple tracks on the page, it makes sense that you would have multiple meta tags.

Perhaps you need a feature in your app that segregates songs allowing you to present a "song page" where you could be specific with your meta data.  This would have the advantage of displaying all details appropriately when shared.

I suggest you check out the developer reference for object types and structure your tags appropriately.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph#object-type

One might also think to use jQuery / Javascript to conditionally add / remove tags.

This is unlikely to work:
[Is it possible to use javascript to change the meta-tags of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568760/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-to-change-the-meta-tags-of-the-page)

Outside of the generic reference facebook also has open graph music, which appears to be restricted to approved partners only, but may be worth a look : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music