# meta viewport and media screen manipulate

Tags: html, css, viewport, meta-tags, responsive

On my site, there is a left side menu, that is 260 pixel wide. Normally it is closed, but when i open it, it push up the page content.

I use this meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I want when the menu is open, the responsive media queries run up that the viewport is the (device viewport - my left menu width)

So i want something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width-260px, initial-scale=1">
```

is it possible in some way?

UPDATE:

Meanwhile I realized that I thought it upon stupid things with thinking meta tag. I want that the media queries in my css run off quickly what I setted.

For example If my css file have: 
`@media screen and (max-width: 720){}`

In this case, Run the css when the window is 460px wide, or as if it were written `@media screen and (max-width: 720){}`, because of my responsive design come apart because it does not change over time when my sidebar is opened and the content is slimmer.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2568915/6327365).  The question there is old but the answer is up to date.  Still, you probably should be using `<div>`s with `position:absolute` instead of changing the `viewport`.

Comment: @grochmal I dont understand, how help the divs with style position absolute. Meanwhile I realized that I thought it upon stupid things with thinking meta tag. I want that the media queries in my css run off quickly what I setted. For example I set `@media screen and (max-width: 460){}` instead of `@media screen and (max-width: 720){}`