# Overwrite Metatag for an automatic generated page

Tags: drupal-7, meta-tags

I have the [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module in drupal 7.4 and it uses the title of the page for the Metatag. However there is one page in particular where the client wants another Metatag, this page is a generated page so I can't adjust it in the backend (with the module). My question is, is there any kind of way where i can adjust this meta tag? `Jquery` or in `template.php` with a check on pagetitle?

Greetings.

Comment: I found this answer about using jQuery to change meta tag [click link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4251913/2665987)

Comment: [Cross-post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/208203/9223)