# Change meta tags according to current route in Aurelia app

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

I'm just learning Aurelia and I was wondering if there's something equivalent to ngMeta for Aurelia or maybe I can just put the aurelia-app custom attribute on the html tag instead of the body so meta tags can be changed according to the current route?
Something like:

```
<html aurelia-app>
  <head>
    <meta name="description" value="${site_description}">
    <title>${site_title}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wonder if this would have any real effect? Would Google see the various site descriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In aurelia you can change page title by special command on `activate` event:

```
activate(params, routeConfig){
  routeConfig.navModel.setTitle(this.someData);
}
```

If you want to change meta tags then you can use jquery

```
import $ from 'jquery';

export class SampleModel{

  attached(){
    $('meta[name=description]').remove();
    $('head').append( '<meta name="description" content="this is new">' );
  }

}
```

More solutions in javascript: [Is it possible to use javascript to change the meta-tags of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568760/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-to-change-the-meta-tags-of-the-page/2568915#2568915)

Comment: It seems this approach changes the meta tags after the page is accessed by search engine or social network crawlers. They will not run the js code and will not see the meta tags changed.

Comment: Sorry, it seems google search engine is capable of rendering the dynamic meta tags https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html, but not social networks