# Open graph tags not working in Blogger

Tags: blogger, facebook-opengraph

This are the open graph tags that i used inside the `</head>` tag of my Blogger blog :

```
<meta expr:content='data:post.dateHeader' property='article:published_time'/>
<meta expr:content='data:post.lastUpdatedISO8601' property='article:modified_time'/>
<meta expr:content='data:label.name' property='article:tag'/>
```

but from the page source of one of my blog posts i got this :

```
<meta content='' property='article:published_time'/>
<meta content='' property='article:modified_time'/>
<meta content='' property='article:tag'/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These data layout tags will only work if they are added between the statement -

```
<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
<!-- Your Code -->
</b:loop>
```

This `b:loop` is present inside the `Blog` widget.

If these data layout tags are used outside that `b:loop` statement, then they won't work because Blogger won't be able to find the dictionary of `data:post` (The globally available dictionaries in Blogger themes are `data:blog` , `data:view` , `data:skin` , `data:widgets` and `data:messages`)

To test this, add the following data layout tag in the `<head>` of the theme code -

```
<data:post.dateHeader/>
```

Now, if you see the page source, you will notice the following comment -

```
<!--Can't find substitution for tag [post.dateHeader]-->
```

Comment: _"To turn your web pages into graph objects, you need to add basic metadata to your page. We've based the initial version of the protocol on RDFa which means that you'll place additional <meta> tags in the <head> of your web page."_ i found this information from [Open graph protocol website](http://ogp.me/)

Comment: Though i added those codes below `<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>` but not working

Comment: @SifaturRahman For making them working inside the Blog widget, use these codes instead - `<meta expr:content='data:post.date.iso8601' property='article:published_time'/>` and 
`<meta expr:content='data:post.lastUpdated.iso8601' property='article:modified_time'/>` For adding all the labels of the post to a meta tag, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43824583/use-blogger-post-labels-as-meta-data-keywords/43867501#43867501

Comment: That is working! So what is the code for the `article:tag` property?

Comment: actually this code worked `<meta expr:content='data:post.dateHeader' property='article:published_time'/>
<meta expr:content='data:post.lastUpdatedISO8601' property='article:modified_time'/>'` but still the `article:tag` property showing empty value. So what should i put to get this `article:tag` working? @Prayag Verma

Comment: I added this codes inside the Blog widget `<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
<meta expr:content='data:label.name' property='article:tag'/>
        </b:loop>` now its working! Thanks for your help man! cheers! @Prayag Verma