# Change meta theme-color on vuex state

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, progressive-web-apps

How change meta tag `"theme-color"` on change `Vuex` state?
Using: `Vue, Vuex, register-service-worker, @vue/cli-plugin-pwa`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `dispatch` an event, inside of it, in your store file, change the meta tag like so:

```
document.querySelector('meta[name="theme-color"]').setAttribute("content", yourValueHere);
```

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36073112/2745485