# How to refresh <meta> attribute 'content' with php without refresh entire page?

Tags: php

On my app project, i secures ajax calls with a key passed to client side with the code:

```
<meta name="trans-en" content="<?=$_SESSION['trans-en']?>">
```

And after each operation (ajax call), `$_SESSION ['trans-en]` content is changed by the php code. How to force attribute 'content' of `<meta>` to take the new value without use an ajax call. Just to know if its possible to do.... sorry for my bad english,  i expectes you undertands.

Comment: If the page content is changed, how is that accomplished? Do you use a JavaScript framework in the frontend?

Comment: Yes, i uses jquery. What do you mean by page content is changed??? For the first load

Comment: I'm still not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but maybe you find a helpful solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568760/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-to-change-the-meta-tags-of-the-page/2568915

Comment: @IngoSteinke, at your link i don't find what i want.

Comment: <meta> attr 'content' is taking $_SESSION['...'] on page first load, but when $_SESSION['...'] is changed on execution, <meta> attr 'content' is holding old value, i want to synchronize (<meta> 'content' and $_SESSION['...']) without javascript xhr request for security reason.

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible to do that through php.....

Comment: If you want to change a head element like meta dynamically, you need to use javascript. With php only, you would have to send a new html document (without ajax) that contains the new meta tag.

Comment: Ok guy, but its difficult.... I will think on it.