# How to dynamically add meta tags for seo and social share in react js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I am currently working on a news website using react js (backend expres.js rest API). This site needs social share functionality with the image and title of the post. I add meta tags using a helmet. I tried to pre-render packages too, Even though this does not show images of the post when sharing. Can I achieve this using API without server-side rendering? please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this using [next.js](https://nextjs.org/) (the react framework). This can make API call and generate HTML in the server. With this, SEO and sharing with title and image are working properly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, while you can change meta tags with javascript (see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568760/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-to-change-the-meta-tags-of-the-page) most consumers of meta tags (Facebook, Twitter, etc) request the document from the server, but don't execute any javascript on that page. That way, the scraper consumes less resources, and reduces the number of attack vectors. That means you will need some way to return specific dynamic values in the `<head>` for different URLs from a server. SSR is probably the best way to do that – at this point, there should be enough different tools/options that it shouldn't be too hard, and you don't need to run two different systems to render markup, one server-side, the way you would if you did something like dynamically alter the contents of your index page.