# React CRA + dotnet core to generate dynamic meta tags

Tags: reactjs, .net, asp.net-core, single-page-application

Looking for a design solution, instead of code.

My app is written in React (using CRA) with dotnet core. I have used Helmet to populate meta and og tags. Subpages are dynamic and based on routes. And they load data via backend api (dotnet core). All works well in the browser, but doesn't work for crawlers for SEO.

Have tried using node server, to dynamically change index.html based on path. But unless I run the node server separately, it doesn't work at all. And only hitting the node server hosted url it renders the dynamic content as pre-render.

Don't want to convert to Next.js, as it will mean re-writing/refactoring most of the app.

Had a failed attempt to try react-helmet-async. No documentation/article covers how to do it for React + dotnet.

Tried a failed attempt to serve index.html from controller.

Tried a failed attempt to do app.UseStaticFiles with onPrepareResponse, doesn't work either.

How do other people do it?

Comment: You can dynamically create your <header> server-side.... but if a full page reload does not happen (seems like React would be single-page-app and only the first hit would be full page load) then the header is unchanged.  I've never considered changing that during standard Ajax call updates, but seems like you could do the same.  Whether the bots would actually re-read them I'm not sure though...(checks if/when an update happened?) see this post for updating meta tags in JS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568760/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-to-change-the-meta-tags-of-the-page

Comment: It seems like combining the two will make it super complicated. I am inclined towards segregating it. And re-write front-end using Nextjs

Comment: By "CRA" do you mean `create-react-app.dev`?

Comment: _"How do other people do it?"_ - in my own SPAs I use ASP.NET MVC to generate `index.html` dynamically (i.e. it's a `.cshtml` view file - but served _as though_ its name is `index.html`).

Comment: _"Tried a failed attempt to serve index.html from controller."_ - **how/why did it fail?**, that's an important detail...